# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (Reading '***')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am new to javascript, react, etc and have been trying to learn by following some youtube videos.
I'm looking for a little support on an issue that I have come up against after following a Youtube video.

Please give me patience. Any assistance will be appreciated. I'm half expecting a few sarcastic responses, so please be kind.

In short, I was following this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvH70UkbyfE

I got all the way through the video and receive no errors in visual studio. However, when I open on my local host I get lots of these errors:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (Reading '***')
```

My code is below:

**App.JS file:**

```
import "./App.css";
import Form from "./Components/Form";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Form.Js File (held in a components folder in the app project folder**

```
import React from "react";
import "../App.css";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
    Name: yup.string().required(),
    AddressLine1: yup.string().required(),
    AddressLine2: yup.string().required(),
    AddressLine3: yup.string().required(),
    AddressLine4: yup.string().required(),
    City: yup.string().required(),
    StateProvinceCounty: yup.string().required(),
    Postcode: yup.string().required(),
    Country: yup.string().required(),

})

function Form() {
    const {register, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema)});

const submitForm = (data) =>{
    console.log(data);
};

    return (
        <div className= "Form">
            <div className="title"> Details</div>
            <div className="inputs">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
                    <input type="text" 
                    name="Name" 
                    placeholder=" Name" 
                    ref={register}/>
                    <p>{errors.Name?.message}</p>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="AddressLine1" 
                        placeholder="AddressLine1" 
                        ref={register}
                    />
                    <p>{errors.AddressLine1?.message}</p>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="AddressLine2" 
                        placeholder="AddressLine2" 
                        ref={register}
                    />
                    <p>{errors.AddressLine2?.message}</p>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="AddressLine3" 
                        placeholder="AddressLine3" 
                        ref={register}
                    />
                    <p>{errors.AddressLine3?.message}</p>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="AddressLine4" 
                        placeholder="AddressLine4" 
                        ref={register
                    }/>
                    <p>{errors.AddressLine4?.message}</p>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="City" 
                        placeholder="City" 
                        ref={register}
                    />
                    <p>{errors.City?.message}</p>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="StateProvinceCounty" 
                        placeholder="City" 
                        ref={register}
                    />
                    <p>{errors.StateProvinceCounty?.message}</p>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="Postcode" 
                        placeholder="City" 
                        ref={register}
                    />
                    <p>{errors.Postcode?.message}</p>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="Country" 
                        placeholder="City" 
                        ref={register}
                    />
                    <p>{errors.Country?.message}</p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Form;
```

**Index.Js File**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Can anyone assist in why i get the issue?

.................................................................

Comment: try to add `?` in every errors, like `errors?.Name?.message `

Comment: > (Reading '***')
Can you tell us what are the stars ?

Comment: Hi. Sorry this was happening on each of the below:
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')
    at Form (Form.js:37:1)

Comment: I just realised on name there is an additional space so it read " Name" but i corrected this and issue was still present.

Comment: I tried adding ? This has changed error type to Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function.

Comment: Thank you so much chaps. I actually got this working. On analysis, it was a change from v6 to v7. :)

Comment: if fixed please provide an answer and mark as accepted